# I am unable to access CSS styles in document.styleSheets[…].cssRules[…]

Tags: javascript, css

I'm trying to write this function in javascript that dynamically rearranges a specific class of objects under a particular parent element. However, I'm having trouble with some of my variables.

```js
const styleSheet = Array.from(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules);
 //filter to create list that contains only "cartelle" class rulesets 
const myRules = styleSheet.filter(ruleset => ruleset.selectorText.includes("cartelle"))

 //iterate along each ruleset in the list
let cardSetLength = Object.keys(myRules).length;
console.log(cardSetLength);
for (let i = 0; i < cardSetLength; i++) {
  //obtain value of the following properties in given ruleset
  let newGridColumn = myRules[i][`grid-row-start`];
  let newGridRow = myRules[i][`grid-column-start`];
  console.log(newGridColumn);
  console.log(newGridRow);
}
```

```css
.cartelle {
  grid-row-start: 42;
  grid-column-start: 69;
}
```

the console logs of newGridColumn and newGridRow both return 'undefined' in this instance, and I'm not sure why. The console log of cardSetlength returns a list of 20 dictionaries each representing a ruleset, but each dictionary is empty and I'm not sure if this has to do with some display convention in the console log or an error on my part. Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: What does `console.log(myRules[i])` and `console.log(myRules[i]['grid-row-start'])` displays ? I don't know what is inside `myRules`

Answer (score 0):

You should access the CSS property values from the `style` field of a `CSSRule`.

```js
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].backgroundColor); // undefined
console.log(document.styleSheets[0].cssRules[0].style.backgroundColor);
```

```css
.class {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

Your code should look something like this:

```js
for (const rule of myRules) {
    let newGridColumn = rule.style[`grid-row-start`];
    let newGridRow = rule.style[`grid-column-start`];
    // ...
}
```

Note that you can use camel case for CSS properties in JavaScript instead of bracket notation.

Comment: It should probably be `gridRowStart` and `gridColumnStart`, like the other hyphenated CSS properties.

Comment: @user3840170 Both ways work, actually (see here: https://jsfiddle.net/j4xeu9t7/). I do prefer using camel case as it works directly with dot notation (I had noted that in the last sentence of my answer).